# Query is responding nothing - firestore javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

It was working fine a day before, but this morning it's just refused to go forward.

Firestore query is responding nothing, no errors, no response.

Even though in console, **phone** is printing fine. And it also exist in db. It was working perfectly fine a day before.

```
db.collection('users').where('mobile_no', '==', phone).limit(1).get().then(function(userSnapshot){
    if (userSnapshot.size > 0) {
      userSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          console.log("EMAIL DATA:"+JSON.stringify(doc.data()));
          if (doc.data().email == '-' || doc.data().email == undefined || doc.data().email == '') {

            thisclass.setState({
              stateReady: true
            })
            // window.location = '/dashboard'
          }else{
            if (fire.auth().currentUser.emailVerified) {
                thisclass.setState({
                  isEmail: true,
                  stateReady: true,
                  emailVerified: true
                })
                //window.location = '/dashboard'
            }else{
                thisclass.setState({
                  isEmail: true,
                  stateReady: true,
                  emailVerified: false
                })
            }

          }
      })

    }else{
      console.log("USER IN Dashboard NOt Exist");

    }
}).catch(function(error){
  console.log("ERROR:"+error);
})
```

It is not displaying **snapShot.size** , no **doc.data()** as well as no **errors** it seems like query is not running at all.

What could be wrong?

I am using reactjs with firebase

Comment: did you change anything?

Comment: no i did not changed anything.

Comment: Try looking at the requests tab in your browser's developer console. See if there are any which stand out to you (e.g. ones that aren't going through).

Comment: Firebase is down for me also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now, with the same code above. Seems like firebase was down. But they did not had mentioned in firebase status. (it was all up and running in status while i was posting this question)